# odoo sever error log: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'json' but called with a request of type 'http'

Tags: angular, ionic4, angular-httpclient, json-rpc, odoo-13

I have an **ionic 4** application and i try to call **odoo jsonrpc** but when request reached to the server there I see the log like '/web/session/authenticate: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'JSON' but called with a request of type 'HTTP''

Same request i send from postman it works.. but from Ionic4 HttpClient post request not responding.

Comment: Hey there, did you solve this issue? I'm ending with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting in the header of your request: `Content-Type`: `application / json`.